# Backup software (that runs on Windows) to burn files and folders to DVD every week?

Tags: windows-7, backup, dvd, scheduled-tasks, burning

Has anyone successfully burned a selection of folders (I'm sure you must have!) to disk every certain amount of time (scheduled)? I'm looking for a solution where I could leave a blank disk in one of my computers every weekend and have a backup ready the next morning. And I'm running Windows 7 RC Build 7100 on this particular machine.

Thanks!

Yasser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com) can be setup with command-line options.  [Here's a link](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?s=2b7a22e7ce68311e197083e49018cebf&showtopic=10596&view=findpost&p=96097) to a post showing a batch file you could use in scheduled tasks.

Comment: I checked your link and that's a little complicated for me! Is there anything simpler?